# How to work with com objects in a background thread Python?

Tags: python, com, watchdog

I use python watchdog to check for new files in folder. If a file appears, then it needs to be processed. Dispatch not working when i call method get_reports from handler. What am I doing wrong?

```
class CustomHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def on_created(self, event):
        try:
            print('{} {}'.format(event.src_path, event.event_type))
            get_reports(event.src_path)
        except Exception as ex:
            w = ex
            print (w)
            write_log(w)


path = config.get("Watcher", "in_dir")
event_handler = CustomHandler()
observer = PollingObserver()


def start_listen():    
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while observer.isAlive():
            observer.join(1)
    finally:
        observer.stop()
        observer.join()
```

```
def get_reports(filter_path):
    user_name = config.get(branch, "user_name")
    user_password = config.get(branch, "user_password")
    server_name = config.get(branch, "server_name")
    connection_name = config.get(branch, "connection_name")
    cc = Dispatch(connection_name)

    if not cc.IsOpen:
        try:
            cc.Open(server_name, user_name, user_password)
        except Exception as er:
            pass
    ***other operations***
```

I tried to use pythoncom.CoInitialize() but with no success

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. Second: don't use `except: pass` because you may have some error and you don't know it - you should at least use `print(er)`. Thrid: are you sure it should be `IsOpen` ? Maybe it has to be `IsOpen()` with `()`

Comment: When a method get_reports is called from a method on_created Dispatch throw error "CoInitialize has not been called". But if i add CoInitialize then Dispatch doesn't work

Comment: @furas the variables are all right, the data in them is correct, but Dispatch is not executed if the callback is not called from the main thread. I omitted part of the code and only highlighted the problematic part. except: pass for example only. IsOpen is correct. It's a property of imported module